# How long in app purchase transactionReceipt data live?

Tags: iphone, ios4, in-app-purchase, storekit

Does anybody know how long in app purchase data live in transactionReceipt variable after making purhcase? How fast i need to send it to my php server to verify the receipt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IAP don't have any expiration date, and I believe you don't really need to verify the receipt on the server.

If you want to go through the receipt validation on server then you need to store some information about user at the time of purchase. which can not be the UDID because of two reason.
 1. UDID is deprecated.
 2. it will not work if user wants to restore on second device.

What you can do is create a unique from the receipt you get from Apple.Each receipt has transaction id and date you can create key out of it to identify user across multiple devices.

Comment: Why not just use the receipt itself for that purpose? Why do you need to store anything?

Comment: I know you don't need that was just a option if you need server validation. and storing and comparing all the receipt on server will be a huge operation as compare to some key created out of trasaction id and date.

Answer (score 3):

It is, in principle, valid forever. Receipts don't expire in general, and in app purchase receipts specifically never expire.